# Getting a formatted list from a pre-generated .toc file

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I have a pre-generated .toc file from another `memoir` LaTeX file (say A). Among others,
this LaTeX file uses `hyperref` (that means, `\contentsline` now has four arguments). From this .toc file, I need
to generate a formatted list in *another* LaTeX file (say B).
The chapter and section names will appear without any page number.
The section names will be comma separated list.

In order to achieve the above, I have tried to tweak various parameters and macros. Please
see below, where, hopefully, the comments will show what I have tried so far:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{filecontents}

% Hide the links
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.tocin.tex}
\contentsline {chapter}{Contents}{1}{section*.1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}One Chapter}{3}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}A Section}{3}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{AA}{3}{section*.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}B}{3}{section.1.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}C}{3}{section.1.3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {2}Another Chapter}{5}{chapter.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}D}{5}{section.2.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.2}E}{5}{section.2.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.3}G}{5}{section.2.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.4}H}{5}{section.2.4}
\end{filecontents*}

% Suppres dots
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionleader}{\hfill}

% Suppress section numbers 
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{}

% Suppress page numbers
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterformatpnum}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionformatpnum}[1]{}

% Show upto sections
\maxtocdepth{section}

% Redefine \l@section to control appearance of section names
\makeatletter
\def\l@section#1#2{\ifnum \@nameuse{c@tocdepth} > 0\relax \vskip \@nameuse {cftbeforesectionskip} 
  {\newcommand*\cftwhatismyname {section}\memRTLleftskip 
    \@nameuse {cftsectionindent}\relax\memRTLrightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\memRTLrightskip \parindent 
    \@nameuse {cftsectionindent}\relax\@afterindenttrue \interlinepenalty \@M \leavevmode 
    \settowidth {\@tempdima }{\@nameuse {cftsectionfont}{\@nameuse {cftsectionname}}}
    \addtolength {\@tempdima }{\@nameuse {cftsectionnumwidth}}
    \expandafter \let \expandafter \@cftbsnum \csname cftsectionpresnum\endcsname 
    \expandafter \let \expandafter \@cftasnum \csname cftsectionaftersnum\endcsname 
    \expandafter \let \expandafter \@cftasnumb \csname cftsectionaftersnumb\endcsname 
    \expandafter \let \expandafter \@cftn@me \csname cftsectionname\endcsname 
    \advance \memRTLleftskip \@tempdima \null \nobreak \hskip -\memRTLleftskip 
    {\@nameuse {cftsectionfont}{#1,}}\nobreak \@nameuse {cftsectionfillnum}{#2}}
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\@input {\jobname.tocin.tex}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

The output is a list without the section or page numbers.

[image]

However, I would like to make the section name list a comma separated
horizontal one like the following.

> ```
> 1 One Chapter
>   A Section, B, C
>
> 2 Another Chapter
>   D, E, G, H
> ```

As you can see, there are at least two problems in my attempted solution:

1. The list is not horizontal.
2. I need to remove the comma after the last section name in list.

---

Due to the prevailing situation, modifying the .toc of LaTeX file A
is not an option.

Comment: How do you want the subsection entries to appear? Inlining them together with the section entries would look like a dog's breakfast.

Comment: with `\maxtocdepth{section}` subsections shouldn't appear in toc.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer As you can see from the above comment, it is upto section level, which I want to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution could be achieved by storing the section name texts in a macro which are rendered together after each chapter. The toggle switches helped us to keep in track, including inter element commas.

---

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.tocin.tex}
\contentsline {chapter}{Contents}{1}{section*.1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}One Chapter}{3}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}A}{3}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{AA1}{3}{section*.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{AA2}{3}{section*.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}B}{3}{section.1.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}C}{3}{section.1.3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {2}Another Chapter}{5}{chapter.2}
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {3}Yet Another Chapter}{7}{chapter.3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {4}And Yet Another Chapter}{9}{chapter.4}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.1}Definitely a Long Section Name: Does It Work Correctly?}{9}{section.4.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.2}Definitely We Make It a Longer Section Name: Does It Also Work Correctly?}{9}{section.4.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.3}E}{9}{section.4.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.4}G}{9}{section.4.4}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.5}H}{9}{section.4.5}
\end{filecontents*}

% Suppres dots
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionleader}{\hfill}

% Suppress section numbers 
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{}

% Suppress page numbers
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterformatpnum}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionformatpnum}[1]{}

% Show upto sections
\maxtocdepth{section}

% Section indents
\cftsetindents{section}{0.0mm}{0.0mm}

% Redefine \contentsline. Retain the original definition somewhere for
% later use
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{sectionst@rted}
\togglefalse{sectionst@rted}
\let\memoir@contentsline\contentsline
\gdef\s@vedsections{}
\def\contentsline#1#2#3#4{%
  % Chapter?
  \ifstrequal{#1}{chapter}
  {
    % If saved section name contents is not empty, render these. These
    % texts are actually from previous chapter
    \ifx\s@vedsections\empty\else
    \memoir@contentsline{section}{\s@vedsections}{}{}\fi
    % Render chapter name text
    \memoir@contentsline{#1}{#2}{}{}
    % Toggle switch for sections previously started
    \global\togglefalse{sectionst@rted}
    % Empty the section name contents repository
    \gdef\s@vedsections{}}{}
  % Section?
  \ifstrequal{#1}{section}
  {
    % Are we already rendering sections?
    \iftoggle{sectionst@rted}
    % Already rendering section true
    {\g@addto@macro\s@vedsections{, #2}}
    % Already rendering section false
    {\global\toggletrue{sectionst@rted}
      \g@addto@macro\s@vedsections{#2}}}{}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\@input {\jobname.tocin.tex}
% Render section text list for the very last chapter
\ifx\s@vedsections\empty\else
\memoir@contentsline{section}{\s@vedsections}{}{}\fi
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well, now there is a bit more voodoo ... in order to place the commas only where we want them, we save the section headings in the macro `\lastsection` and push them out with a comma only after the next one is read; the last one is pushed out without a comma by the next `chapter` line.

This requires that we insert a `\lastsection` at the end of the document to typeset the last `\contentsline{section}{...}`, which would otherwise simply be forgotten.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen, hanging}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
\newlength{\chapindent}
\setlength{\chapindent}{0.25in}
\setlength{\parindent}{\chapindent}

\newcommand{\lastsection}{}
\newcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{\makebox[\chapindent][l]{#1}}
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{}

\renewcommand{\contentsline}[4]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{chapter}}{\lastsection\renewcommand{\lastsection}{}%
\par\noindent{#2}}%
     {\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{section}}{%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{\lastsection}{}}{\par\hangpara{\chapindent}{-100}}{\lastsection,\hspace{\chapindent}}%
     \renewcommand{\lastsection}{#2}}{}}%
\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\contentsline {chapter}{Contents}{1}{section*.1}%
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}One Chapter}{3}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}A Section}{3}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}A Section}{3}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}A Section}{3}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.4}A Section}{3}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.5}A Section}{3}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.6}A Section}{3}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.7}A Section}{3}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{AA}{3}{section*.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.8}B}{3}{section.1.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.9}C}{3}{section.1.3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {2}Another Chapter}{5}{chapter.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}D}{5}{section.2.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.2}E}{5}{section.2.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.3}G}{5}{section.2.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.4}H}{5}{section.2.4}
% push out the last section heading 
\lastsection

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to get the commas as well between section names except after the last section name in a list.

Comment: @Masroor - see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The mandatory [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) solution.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.tocin.tex}
\contentsline {chapter}{Contents}{1}{section*.1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}One Chapter}{3}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}A Section}{3}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{AA}{3}{section*.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}B}{3}{section.1.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}C}{3}{section.1.3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {2}Another Chapter}{5}{chapter.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}D}{5}{section.2.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.2}E}{5}{section.2.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.3}G}{5}{section.2.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.4}H}{5}{section.2.4}
\end{filecontents*}

% Hide the links
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,hidelinks]{hyperref}

% Show upto sections
\maxtocdepth{section}

\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter of master doc}

\section{A section in master doc}

\chapter{Second chapter of master doc}

\section{A section in second chapter of master doc}

Here is now the table of contents of the other file. The first heading
``Contents'' comes from that file, actually.

\begingroup
\makeatletter

% Suppress dots
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionleader}{\hfill}

% Suppress section numbers 
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{}

% Suppress page numbers
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterformatpnum}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionformatpnum}[1]{}

\let\original@l@chapter\l@chapter
\let\original@chapternumberline\chapternumberline

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
   {}
   {\original@l@chapter
    {\original@chapternumberline{\etocthenumber}\etocthename}{\etocthepage}}
   {}
   {}
\etocsetstyle{section}
   {\normalfont}
   {\etociffirst{\noindent}{, }\etocthename}
   {}
   {\par}

% Trick etoc into using other file
{\newread\Etoc@tf
 \openin\Etoc@tf \jobname.tocin.tex
 \global\Etoc@toctoks{}%
 \endlinechar=\m@ne
 \Etoc@readtoc
 \global\Etoc@toctoks=\expandafter{\the\Etoc@toctoks}%
 \closein\Etoc@tf}

% adjust as desired
\etocsettocstyle{}{\bigskip}

\etocsetnexttocdepth{section}

\tableofcontents* % the star is to avoid an entry in the main TOC
\endgroup

We will now proceed with our regular radio address.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Skimmed through the `etoc` for the whole afternoon yesterday. Tried to find a solution, gave up when failed to find a way to *trick* `etoc` to use another file. But thanks again. This answer will act a reference when a similar scenario arises in future.

Comment: @Masroor `etoc` manual needs some improvements... but I had to hack it at core level here. There is a problem which is that the `\Etoc@toctoks` is set globally. As a result once the "trick" is applied the `\tableofcontents` etc... will again use the "other file". One would have to store the contents of `\Etoc@toctoks` and restore it afterwards if one wanted to again use `\tableofcontents` or `\localtableofcontents` command next. In my answer, I was a bit handicapped from the fact that I don't know the memoir/toclofct commands, hence the `\saved@l@chapter` etc...

Comment: Just as a side comment, the `etoc` manual somehow fails to nurture the intuition of the reader. The developer/main­tainer (Jean-François Burnol = jfbu?) might consider rewriting the manual. I get the feeling that it is a wonderful tool, but the manual demands a steep learning curve. Perhaps a incremental method will be suitable for a larger audience.

Comment: `etoc` is orthogonal to what people usually expect: i.e. commands to customize things. In fact `etoc` only defines `\etocname`, `\etocnumber`, `\etocpage` and the user has to define a style using those from the ground up. The manual contains many examples, but it can not teach LaTeX. Besides, initially examples preferred core TeX syntax.

Comment: I forgot to state that the master document must be using `hyperref` too, this is needed for `etoc` to interpret correctly the custom toc file. Else one needs to execute `\def\Etoc@et@hop#1#2#3#4#5{#2{#3}{#4}#1}%` and 
`\long\def\Etoc@gobblefourorthree#1#2#3#4{}%` locally in the `\begingroup .. \endgroup` with the custom `\tableofcontents*`.

Comment: last thing: the reason the code uses `\etocthename` and not `\etocname` is that the latter (if `hyperref` is loaded in master doc) will try to build a hyperlink, which however will be all wrong or cause `hyperref` warnings, because its id will come from the custom file and have nothing to do with ids of the master doc. The `\etocthename` is freed of any `hyperref` decoration.